# how to remove a record with phpmysql

Tags: php, html

An html form is part of the code which l have intentionally decided not to include. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
    <?php
 require('db.php');
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM new_record WHERE id=$id"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());
header("Location: view.php"); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have an auto incrementing primary key column in your table, but its best if you have one so you can easily update individual records

First you will need to change your SELECT query (or run a new one) and set a WHERE clause to select database entry.

Then change the INSERT script to this:

```
$insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE people SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, bio = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$insert->bind_param('sssi', $firstName, $lastName, $bio, $id);
```

Where $id is the id of the entry in your 'people' database that you got from the SELECT query you ran earlier.

Answer (score -1):

For edit you to have to make a logic, like make this

```
<td><input type="button" class="btn-info" name="btn" value="Edit"></td>
```

to a href,

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?= $r->id ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Supposing id as primary key, and on this new page make a edit form, save it and redirect here.